# Having an arrow on the left side of my colored div

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have the following rectangle box (this is a div) and I would like to represent an arrow on the left side. I was searching for a really simple way of doing but every solution I found is a little tricky for my purpose.

```
<div class="redbox">
    <b>Hello world</b>
</div>

 .redbox {
   display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
   background-color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3N6yP/

**How to transform this simple div to show an arrow on the left side?**

Something like it:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here am using a CSS triangle which is positioned `absolute` to the element, and than and using `:before` pseudo, so that, it creates virtual element for you. This will just save you few characters in the DOM. Just make sure you use `position: relative;` for the element having class `.redbox`, so that the `absolute` positioned virtual element doesn't fly away in the wild.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3N6yP/2/)

```
.redbox:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 15px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right:15px solid #f00; 
    top: 0;
    left: -15px;
}
```

Comment: The solution you suggested is what I was trying at first. The problem I have with this solution is I need to control the color used conditionally directly from my html page. Do you think this is possible? Thanks.

Comment: @Bronzato Can you explain a bit, as am not getting you

Comment: For example: I need to color this element into green or red based on some other elements on my page (so conditionnally). This would be great if I can add another class aside `redbox` to control the color to use. Do you see what I mean? For example `<div class="mybox red">` to have this box painted in red.

Comment: @Bronzato you can add and remove classes using JS. If you want, you can use a `span` instead of virtual element, and add the class to the DOM on load.. that will suffice your requirement :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this cross-browser generator: http://cssarrowplease.com/

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the "border trick" sometimes has unpredictable margin offsets across different browsers (and of course depending on your markup) and prefer other methods.

I'd personally use a proven method and use an image. Depending on your situation you can just have one sprite image or you can wrap your arrow and content.

http://jsfiddle.net/3N6yP/5/

HTML:

```
<div class="redbox">
    <span></span><div>Hello World</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.redbox {
   display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
   background-color: red;

}
.redbox div{
    height:30px;
    background:#ff0000;
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:30px;
}

.redbox span{
    float:left;
    display:block;
    height:30px;
    width:20px;
     background:#333333 url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUsjz.png) center left no-repeat;
}
```